Can i change the sound on this circuit board?
I'm trying to change the sound that is playing from this circuit board but I dont know if it's even possible. It has two Led numbers on each side. A slide button which turns on or off the sound. One button to the left which resets the count and one to the right that turns of the panel. Can I use this somehow to change the prerecorded sound?
Sorry for the quality of the picture was limited to the length of the speakercable on how much I could turn it.


Being possible is a different question than what expertise and tools it will take to achieve it and how. Technically, it may be simpler to build your own board than to reverse-engineer and learn how to change it on the existing board.

If the sound that is played is really simple (a few beeps of the same tone say), then it might be possible with a passive component change. But if the sound is anything more complex (like a short tune or something) then it is likely that the tune is pre-recorded and saved to a microcontroller. Changing this would be very difficult or potentially impossible.

Thanks for your answer, Then I guess I have to learn how to make my own board instead of reverse-engineer it like Justme commented
